# Custom user library folder in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, tomcat9

I need to include a few custom `jar` files in `Tomcat` that are referenced by a `Java` web application deployed on `Tomcat`.

If I add these libraries under `<tomcat_base_folder>/lib`, my application work perfectly fine, but I wanted to check if I can logically group them and move to different folders and modify any config files on `Tomcat` to pick these additional locations.

For example, can I create a folder by name `drivers` under `<tomcat_base_folder>` and add the `ojdbc` and `db2cc` jar files under this folder and reference the `drivers` folder also in the classpath somehow? Is there a way to include the custom library locations?

Appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in Tomcat's [class-loader-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions), you need to edit `conf/catalina.properties` and add your libraries to this property : `common.loader`

The syntax is quite self understanding.

Comment: Thank you @eugène-adell, that worked like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks to Tomcat community which brings configurable software ;)